# AWS S3 Stop Download Image automatically when browsed via URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading images to my S3 bucket via my Node.js Application. I have the following bucket policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I go to the link of the file lets say its an image. It automatically downloads as a file and does not render in the browser. Any idea how to make it display in the browser without automatically force downloading the image in the browser?

Comment: the image is public? And link should be 
http(s)://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object_key>

Comment: yes it is public just tht it downloads automatically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicitly set the [`Content-Type`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax) of the object with `image/<appropriate-subtype>`.

```
var params = { Bucket: '', Key: '', ContentType: 'image/png',  ... }
```

The default `Content-Type` would be `application/octet-stream`, thus instead of rendering in the browser it is being downloaded.

Comment: Thank you will check it out